# How do I protect my MySQL database/PDO PHP scripts from abuse (inside Android app)?

Tags: android, mysql, security, pdo

Im using MySQL with PDO PHP scripts to maintain a user database and a highscore database.
When a user obtains a new highscore in the Android app, I send it to the server:

```
https://domain.com/phpscript.php?user=username&newhighscore=highscore
```

In here username and highscore are variables. Every web browser can access this url. If anyone decompiles my app they will know where my database is located and they can fake their highscore. Obfuscation and encryption for the url is probably not an option since they can always be reversed.

Is there any way I can protect these URLS so ONLY my Android app can access these pages, and not just any browser?

Comment: Can you describe a little more on what do you mean by `Obfuscation and encryption for the url is probably not an option since they can always be reversed.`?

Comment: @dark crow In my Android app I can encode the url in base64 or encrypt with AES, but I'd have to store the key somewhere in the app as well. Someone who decompiles my app can still reverse to get the real url.

Comment: Why don't you use SSL as described here http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

Comment: @dark crow, Im already using SSL (https).

Comment: Just putting (https) does not mean SSL.

Comment: @dark crow  I'm aware of that. I am using SSL though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a call to `https://domain.com/phpscript.php?user=username&newhighscore=highscore` is all you need to update the highscore for a user, you are in deep sh*t.

You need some sort of authentication - which is what you might mean with "ONLY my Android app can access these pages", here are a few ideas:

- On first start of you app call another script to facilitate exchange of some token. Store this token in your app and in your server-sided DB and use it as a verification token, e.g. `https://domain.com/phpscript.php?user=username&newhighscore=highscore&salt=abc&auth=xyz` with abc being a random salt and xyz something like `hash(encrypt("user=username&newhighscore=highscore",key=token,iv=salt)+salt)`
- use the phone ID as part of the authentication scheme

Comment: `Store this token in your app` - Is this truly secure? At least abuse of other peoples data wont be possible anymore, but is there no easy way to retrieve this token from the app? In which way would you store it? SharedPreferences? --edit-- Also this would prevent reinstalls or multiple devices right? As a new install or other devices generates a new token.

Comment: **Nothing** is truly secure. What you want is to make it secure enough, so that faking a highscore is not worth the effort. Storing a token on the device is definitly more secure than doing nothing - an attacker might (and will) be able to extract the token for this user, but not for other users. If you allow installs on multiple devices with the same username, you already need some password mechanism - or can I just download the app and say "My username is XYY, which happens to be the username of the global highscore holder" ?